# Typescript syntax highlighting of strings in Solarized light

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text, solarized

I just installed the [Typescript plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin). (I tried installing through PackageControl and manually). In Solarized light, the strings (in `'single'` or `"double"` quotes) are the same formatting as default text. They are distinct in Solarized dark, with a different color.

How can I fix this? I assume I should make a change somewhere in the Typescript plugin, but I'm wary because it doesn't seem like strings should be highlighted in dark but not in light.

Just as a sidenote, another difference I see is that comments are formatted differently from normal text in Solarized light, but the same as strings in Solarized dark. I find this confusing, too, but since they are different in light, which is what I'd like to use, it is not a problem.

I'm using Ubuntu and Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I installed the ArcticTypescript Package; better highlighting and autocompletion. Still interested in how I would edit syntax highlighting issues listed above.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24329434/1426065) of mine on Stack Overflow detailing how to edit components of packages and plugins (the question regards a theme, not a color scheme, but the answer is pretty generic). Color schemes are in the `.tmTheme` XML format. A quick Google search will give lots of resources on how to customize them. The [unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) also have a good reference.